# LaTeX and Mathematica

Tags: memoir, wolfram-mathematica

Does anyone any have experience with writing large works (fx. a thesis, BA, ...) in Mathematica and then successfully converting it to LaTeX code of reasonably quality or should I just stick to my trusted **Memoir** class.

Comment: Only marginally related, but Matlab has a similar `publish` command that allows one to generate LaTeX text with intermixed Matlab output. A notable example of a book written using it is [*Approximation Theory and Approximation Practice*](http://www2.maths.ox.ac.uk/chebfun/ATAP/) by LN Trefethen

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use the memoir class and export the code for the mathematica examples from within your LaTeX document. Then run the mathematica examples by a script and insert the created pdfs instead of the source code. Can all be done automatically.